# Booting Ubuntu on USB from Bios

Tags: system-installation

When I open BOOT in BIOS and select my USB Pendrive the setup asks for a file path. What do I enter in the file path?

Comment: how did you set the drive up?

Comment: Hi Chris! Welcome to **AU**. Could you be more specific and add in-detail as how you created the Bootable USB, if this is about Ubuntu; where you've downloaded the iSO from?.. etc. This will help us to identify the problem and assist you better. :)